# Building a Docker-Image with maven and spring-boot on Windows

Tags: java, maven, docker, spring-boot

I'm trying to learn how to use maven, spring-boot and docker to create a web-application. I'm following this guide:

https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/

I managed to build the maven project as such that localhost, says "Hello Docker World".

Then I copied the Dockerfile and added the extra property and plugin.

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <docker.image.prefix>springio</docker.image.prefix>
</properties>
```

...

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
            <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <repository>${docker.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId}</repository>
        <buildArgs>
            <JAR_FILE>target/${project.build.finalName}.jar</JAR_FILE>
        </buildArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

When executing `mvn -N io.takeri:maven:wrapper` to add the maven wrapper I received an error: 
`Error resolving version for plugin 'io.takeri:maven from the repositories[...]: Plugin not found in any plugin repository -> [Help 1]`

As the command above has already worked on a different attempt (without docker) I checked the Help 1-link

https://cwiki.apache.org//confluence/display/maven/pluginresolutionexception

and added the same plugin-repository to the pom.xml as in the other project were it worked.

This proved to be ineffetive.

Executing the Project without the wrapper (mvn install dockerfile:build)

gives a `MojoExecutionException` followed by a long Error-Trace
and the

```
error: Failed to execute goal com.spotify:dockerfile-maven-plugin:1.3.6:build    
(default.cli) on project ...: Could not build image:   
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 
com.spotify.docker.client.shader.javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: 
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:2375    
[localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: 
connect
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Note1: I'm new to Maven AND Spring-Boot AND Docker AND Stackoverflow, please let me know how I can improve this post or learn more about them.

Note2: I'm running Windows 10, and was planning on using Virtual Toolbox for Windows and successfully executed this guide https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/

Answer (score 0):

I wonder what repositories you refer to? Both the takari plugin and spotify plugin are available in maven central, so no repositories should need to be configured in your pom. Or did you add them to your settings.xml? Could you try to simply remove repositories from your project?

Maven distinguishes dependencies and plugins. So you have sources (repositories to download them from) for both, meaning repositories and pluginRepositories. Nowadays companies will use a mirror/proxy like nexus or artifactory, so the difference is not directly visible - you only configure the mirror and point all repositories there.

So to use plugins there must be a pluginRepository configured that contains that plugin. See [settings.xml](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Plugin_Repositories) docs.
Since all you need is in maven central the default config should just work without any more to do. So just remove all repositories from your pom.xml or settings.xml

The docker error you get seems not to be related to maven or the plugin, it simply cannot communicate with your docker host. Maybe to port is wrong or you are running a docker version not compatible with the plugin or it was not running? Docker for Windows might require you to [expose the daemon without TLS](https://github.com/spotify/docker-maven-plugin/issues/351).

Hope any of this is of some help :)

Comment: Thank you for answering. Sadly as I'm pretty new to this so I didn't understand all of it. First of all I have not used a settings.xml and secondly it did not work even in a project referenzing no repositories at all. The checked repositories specified in the error message are: [local (C:\Users\USERNAME\.m2\repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]

Comment: To the second part: I managed to build the dockerfile using the Docker Quickstart Terminal executing ./mvnw install dockerfile:build inside it, probably that is required to that Docker can find the connection?
For obvious reasons the maven wrapper was not added by myself, i did that on the "complete" version of the guide.
Is there any other way to get the wrapper if needed?

Comment: hmm. try "mvn help:effective-settings" and "mvn help:effective-pom" with both mvn and the mvnw wrapper and compare the results. they should behave the same unless some config is different somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. **HttpHostConnectException** You must run docker deamon on your machine.

Answer (score -4):

Maybe you could configure environment variables.

[image]

[image]